# Installing ubuntu 19.10 alongside zorin os 15 with no free space partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 19.10

I want to install new ubuntu 19.10 along side my existing zorin os 15 installation.
Below is the file system partition.

[image: You can see it here]

As you can see out of the 1TB i have in my HDD, all is given to zorin os now.

But when i try to install ubuntu 19.10 via the usb drive it shows me the option to install along side zorin and also gave me a slider to allocate the space for both os's separately.

I was just curious how this can be done, and if I went on with the slider and then install ubuntu along side zoris will it affect my existing system files in zorin or will it be in a state that is completely lost?

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: hi guys, did any one of you did try the above way?

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't got an answer here, I think i need to post my answer.

I go on and did take a chance and installed ubuntu along side zorin. It will partition your hard disk evenly and there won't be any conflicts at all.

It is also possible to replace one partition in the future and install another os.